# Smallest axis-aligned regular hexagon for a set of hexagonal lattice points

Tags: geometry

Given a set of points on a hexagonal lattice, is there an efficient way to compute a center point $c$ and a minimal integer radius $r$ such that all points are within Manhattan distance $r$ of $c$?

The problem for squares on a square lattice is easy—compute the bounding rectangle and lengthen the shorter sides until it is a square.  But I haven't been able to find a reference for how to solve the equivalent problem on a hexagonal lattice.

For context, we are trying to rank solutions in the game [Opus Magnum](https://www.zachtronics.com/opus-magnum/) according to this minimum bounding hexagon.  Here's an example of a solution optimized for its bounding hexagon: https://imgur.com/J8BeLNu.

Comment: "Manhattan distance" is generally defined on a square (or, rectangular) lattice, because that's how the streets & avenues of Manhattan look. What is Manhattan distance on a hexagonal lattice?

Comment: It's the minimum number of steps you need to take between neighboring lattice points in order to travel from one point to another.  I'm not sure whether there's a better name for it.  See https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#distances for code that computes this in various coordinate systems.

Comment: It may be useful to realize the hexagonal lattice as points of $\mathbf{Z}^3$ with $x + y + z = 0$ (and the "Manhattan distance" as twice the usual 1-metric on these points).

Answer (score 1):

This answer gives a way to compute $r$.  Using the axial coordinate system, write points as $(u, v)$.  Define $(u_1, v_1) \perp (u_2, v_2) = u_1u_2 - v_1v_2$.

For a set of points $U$, define $(u, v) \perp U = \max\{ (u, v) \perp p : p \in U \}$.  Then we can write six directional distances:

$$
\begin{split}
d_1 & = (0, -1) \perp U \\
d_2 & = (1, 0) \perp U \\
d_3 & = (-1, 1) \perp U \\
d_4 & = (0, 1) \perp U \\
d_5 & = (-1, 0) \perp U \\
d_6 & = (1, -1) \perp U \\
\end{split}
$$

The value of $r$ is the maximum of these five quantities, rounded up:
$$
r = \left\lceil \max \left\{
\frac{d_1 + d_4}{2},
\frac{d_2 + d_5}{2},
\frac{d_3 + d_6}{2},
\frac{d_1 + d_2 + d_3}{3},
\frac{d_4 + d_5 + d_6}{3}
\right\} \right\rceil.
$$
The first three quantities handle the case where the hexagon's size is determined by points on two opposite sides, while the last two handle the case where the hexagon's size is determined by points on three different sides.